How can I prevent the Snyk extension in VSCode from scanning code automatically on save?
I am using the Snyk extension in VSCode, and by default, it runs a code scan every time I save a file. This is slowing down my workflow And I only want to scan the code manually.
I have looked through the settings but couldn't find an option to turn off the automatic scanning on save.
How can I configure the Snyk extension to prevent it from automatically scanning my code when I save a file? any help on how to change this setting would be appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Well, if there's no setting, there's nothing you can do except modifying the source code of the extension. Assuming you want other formatters etc. to run on save.
